# Simple if-statement logic returning a wrong value

Tags: vb.net

I have the simplest of if statements to work out if a person has passed an exam or not when I run the code the result always comes up as fail.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim EnglishMark As Single
    Dim ScienceMark As Single
    Dim MathsMark As Single
    Dim AverageMark As Single

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        EnglishMark = Val(txtEnglish.Text)
        ScienceMark = Val(txtScience.Text)
        MathsMark = Val(txtMaths.Text)
        AverageMark = (EnglishMark + ScienceMark + MathsMark) / 3 / 100

        If (AverageMark >= 50) Then 
            lblDisplay.Text = "You Passed Well Done" & Format(AverageMark, "Percent") 
        Else 
            lblDisplay.Text = "You Failed Try Again" & Format(AverageMark, "Percent")
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the values of your input fields? Why do you divide it by `100`? That division doesn't make it a percentage (if that's your intention).

Comment: (100+100+100) / 3 / 100 = 1 which is a fail

Comment: What did you observe when you stepped through the code with the debugger?  And your code would be more readable if you did not write your `If` statement all on one line like that.

Comment: You probably need `(EnglishMark + ScienceMark + MathsMark) / (3 * 100)` Also, please don't write an `If-Else` statement in one line like this. The only exception is when it's a _short_ `If` statement _(without an `Else`)_.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use something like `lblDisplay.Text = If(Condition, valueIfTrue, valueIfFalse)`. But also avoid doing that when the expressions are long.